# precompile options for function overloading in C

Tags: c, macros, overloading, precompile

I have a portion of code where i use multiple signature of the same function using precompile switch. The precompile is generated based on configuration supplied. Does this qualify as function overloading?

E.g.

```
#define Number_Of_Cores 1 (generated based on config)

#if(Number_Of_Cores > 1) [Shall be handled by PreProcessor]
FUNCTION_ABC(Core_Identifier);
#else
FUNCTION_ABC();
#endif
```

Comment: Take a look at how C++ achieves function overloading - it fakes it by mangling the name.  You can probably achieve what you need by hacking function pointers - but it would be horrible and you need a really good reason.

Answer (score 3):

No. Based on the value of the precompile switch, either of the code block will get compiled. So, at any given instance of compilation, only one function signature will be available.

Answer (score 1):

No, of course it doesn't.

C doesn't support function overloading.

You never have both functions defined at the same time, so there is no overloading.

In C the only "overloading" is for some built-in operators like `+`, which of course you cannot customize/override as you can in C++.

Comment: Since C11, C has `_Generic` which can be used for function overloading.